# How to fix kernel paging request error on raspberry pi miner?

Tags: cgminer, miner-configuration, linux, raspberry-pi, gridseed

I'm mining Bitcoin and Litecoin using [Gridseeds](http://gridseed.com/product?lang=en).

As a host/controller I'm running a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) with [ArchLinuxARM](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi).

I'm using the latest Arch image and compiled cgminer from this github repository:

https://github.com/girnyau/cgminer-gc3355

I'm running 10 Gridseeds. They are running well at 3.6 MH/s Scrypt (10x 360kH/s @ 850 MHz) until some point when it goes Oops:

```
[ 4565.377848] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00002055
[ 4565.385255] pgd = c9df8000
[ 4565.393214] [00002055] *pgd=c9df8000, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
[ 4565.404992] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMT ARM
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: kernel paging request]

Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: why Arch or Debian? just wanting to know why?

Comment: @PhillPafford I'm using arch on all my devices, that simplyfies so many workflows. The Arch-Pi is very well supported.

Comment: ping me on twitter.com/phillpafford if needed, just looking to make a decision on Arch or Debian ( Wheezy / Raspbian ), just looking for a why choose this one over the other, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494625.msg5932931#msg5932931) and [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=55370):

You have to enable SLUB debugging for your linux kernel. Therefore you have to edit your linux kernel command line:

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Add the following code at the end of the first line (on the same line as the other text, don't add new line!).

```
slub_debug=FP
```

Save the file then reboot your Raspberry Pi.

What the above does is basically enable some kernel debug mode on the Raspberry Pi. The mentioned kernel paging request error seems to be a kernel bug and gets caught by the debugging settings.

The downside is that the overall performance of the raspi is lower. But that does not affect the mining performance at all.

Comment: Has anyone resolved this? I encountered this error in regular raspberry pi operations. So it seems this is a general issue. Has anyone found a solution? A workaround?